# how to empty the sharedpreferences storage in android?

Tags: android

i'm using sharedPreferences to store username and password .. but i need to make log off, how can i remove the data od username and password ?

Comment: try this https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/content/en/Unit%204/91_p_shared_preferences.html

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the SharedPreferences Editor object to do it. You can follow the next example:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.remove("username_field");
editor.remove("password_field");
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to clear the entire preference too, useful if you've only got the users details in the preference, and you want to remove all of that, you Can use.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.clear(); 
editor.commit();
```